# Chrome extension -- prints html error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was building a chrome extension that prints some html in the popup.

I just can't make it to work though:

Here's my code.

***re.js:***

```
function getHTML(document){
    var test = document_r.body;
    var text = test.textContent;
    var bodyStart="<BODY";
    var bodyEnd="</BODY>"
    var regex = bodyStart +"(.*?)"+ bodyEnd;
    var regexg = new RegExp(regex, "g");
    var match = regexg.exec(text);
    return match;
}

chrome.tabs.query( {
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
},
function(array_of_Tabs) {
    var tab = array_of_Tabs[0];
    //tab.url; - url of the active tab
    var htmlStr=getHTML(document);
    var tempDiv=document.createElement('div');
    tempDiv.innerHTML=htmlStr;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "chrome.runtime.sendMessage(temoDiv.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);"});
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = request;
});
```

***popup.html:***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>    
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 300px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 4px;
        border: 3px black;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "HTML opener",
  "description": "Open the current page in popup window",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "HTML opener",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I don't know where am I getting it wrong. Basically what it should do that getHTML document returns a string of the form "..."

I am trying to create a HTML document by tempDiv and dispaly it, where am I getting this wrong.

Comment: what error you are getting??

Comment: Not an error actually. But popup doednt display anything at all